# Is there a way to add up multiple pandas columns conditionally based on text in the column label?

Tags: python, pandas

I am building a dataframe that shows availability in a hotel. The rows are the dates and the columns are the room types. There are 5 columns labelled PD1_Total, PD2_Total, PDSK_Total, PDEK_Total, and PDSU_Total.

I need to create a column that shows all the individual room availability added together. The obvious manual way to do it is with the code:

`ga['Total_Rooms'] = ga['PD1_Total'] + ga['PD2_Total'] + ga['PDSK_Total'] + ga['PDEK_Total'] + ga['PDSU_Total']`

However, the source data may be updated at a later date to include other room types with the suffix '_Total', so I'd like to figure out a way to create that formula to automatically include all the columns with that suffix without having to manually update the formula.

[image]

Thank-you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple list comprehension for column selection might do the trick:

```
ga['Total_Rooms'] = ga[[col for col in ga.columns if col.endswith('_Total')]].sum(axis = 1)
```

Comment: Thank-you Hamza. I marked this one as the most useful answer because I have a better understanding of list comprehensions than I do of regex. But they both work. Very much appreciated.

Comment: `ga.loc[:,ga.columns.str.endswith('_Total')]` is much more readable.

Comment: Hey Quang Hoang! It actually throws an error for me as it will return a list of bools instead of actual column names

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
df['Total_Rooms'] = df.filter(regex='_Total$').sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank-you Wasif. This is an elegant solution that also works, but I haven't learned much about regex yet, so it's something new to learn. Very much appreciated.